# iad not appearing in ios9(xcode)

Tags: swift

This code was working well in iOS 8 but not in iOS 9.

After upgrading to iOS9 and later iAds not showing up. 
Is this is an apple issue or is there any other way to implement it.please post your replies

```
 import UIKit
import iad

class ViewController: UIViewController,ADBannerViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet var adsbannerview: ADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     adsbannerview.hidden = true

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}

 func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("error")
}

  func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

 func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    adsbannerview.hidden = true
}

   func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
  return true
}

}
```

Comment: iAd is shutting down. Unfortunately it will no longer be available after June. This may be why it is not appearing.

Comment: So can you tell its alternate to earn money ? And its code to implement ? @penatheboss

Comment: You could try various third party advertisements. Google offers advertising for iOS.